# Do the dragons in Game of Thrones have a limited number of fire breaths?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

I was watching "The Long Night" and in the scene where the good team was looking out for Dany and Drogon to light up the trenches (but she was trapped in snowstorm), while Jon and Rhaegal were just next to the trenches. Hence the Red Woman has to fill up for her.

So I wanted to know, did Rhaegal have any limit of fire 'shot count' (similar to that seen in *How to Train Your Dragon*) which it exhausted at the start of the battle?

[image]

Comment: You're aware that HTTYD and GoT are completely different right?

Comment: I've edited to try to make a little more sense.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - A crossover would be awesome. Poor Hiccup getting beheaded in the first episode though.

Comment: yes @TheLethalCarrot I am aware HTTYD and GOT are not related, but in that storyline, they had a reference that every dragon has a 'shot limit' so I gave that reference for better understandability of my query

Comment: there can be case of limited fire breaths, as rhaegal and viserion were raised in captavity, while drogon was wild, leading to small size and maybe lesser abillites.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I'm aware, there is no "shot count" to dragons in *Game of Thrones* and in *A Song of Ice and Fire* as well. It's hard to prove a negative but it's never mentioned or made into a plot point so it is highly unlikely to be something.

I think your confusion is two fold here:

- *How to Train Your Dragon* and *Game of Thrones* are not the same. The worlds, universes, lores and rules of one work are not the same in the other. There are shot counts in HTTYD but not in GoT. The two are completely separate works.
- Dany didn't light the trench because she couldn't see the signal. There's not much more to it than that, she couldn't see the torch signal in the snowstorm so didn't know to light the trench. It's not that Drogon, or Rhaegal, have shot counts. The only reason fire arrows and Melisandre had to step in was because Dany couldn't see the signal to act on it.

For the part about Jon and Rhaegal though. Jon was near the Godswood to stay close to Bran, he wasn't near the front gate where the signal was given. He didn't know the trenches needed lighting at that point to be able to light them and he couldn't just randomly do it because that would trap their forces.

Comment: A certain scene in the last season pretty much proves that dragons have "infinite ammo" in terms of fire-breathing.

Comment: @Snow Aye, I didn't want to argue that point though because someone could just say "they could just have a high count".

Comment: after the fight against viseron jon headed toward godswood, before then he was sitting casually near the trenches seeing red woman doing magic

Comment: @AshishYadav he was at the trenches near the Godswood, not near the front gate where the signal was given.